# "Error: Loading Chunk X failed" when accessing some lazy-loaded route modules in Angular 8 on IOS only

Tags: ios, lazy-loading, angular8

### Problem Description

In our Angular 8 project, some of the routes are loaded lazily using the following syntax

```js
{
  path: "/bread",
  loadChildren: () => import('./bread/bread.module')
   .then(m => m.BreadModule)
}
```

All routes work very fine in almost all Desktop and Android devices browsers - including macOS Safari - (a list of tested working environments below), but **some of the lazy-loaded routes are failing when tested on IOS devices**. When trying to access these routes, whether programmatically or by manually setting the URL of the browser, the following error shows on the console :

```
ERROR ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading chunk 5 failed.
(missing: https://192.168.220.128/ui/5.962e65be9c4b000c89f6.js)
a@https://192.168.220.128/ui/runtime.b5d7c083c76af74c6510.js:1:1269
P@https://192.168.220.128/ui/polyfills.27aa9b55940b8e5475a1.js:1:18520
onInvokeTask@https://192.168.220.128/ui/main.1b4a84881faf77e4effa.js:1:144508
https://192.168.220.128/ui/polyfills.27aa9b55940b8e5475a1.js:1:3483
https://192.168.220.128/ui/polyfills.27aa9b55940b8e5475a1.js:1:9381
y@https://192.168.220.128/ui/polyfills.27aa9b55940b8e5475a1.js:1:22586
_@https://192.168.220.128/ui/polyfills.27aa9b55940b8e5475a1.js:1:22811
```

### Tried solutions

Here's a list of the solutions we tried but in vain:

- Adding a global `ExceptionHandler` that detects the error and forces the website to reload. It keeps reloading forever.
- Hard-resetting the broswer. Actually we are using [Lampdatest](https://lambdatest.com) Realtime Broswer testing and everytime a new test starts, the browser is clean.
- Some hacks, like scratching heads, drinking more coffee and redirecting to a buffer page that then redirects to the actual route.

### Some solutions we didn't/couldn't try/implement due to some limitations

- Anything PWA
- Preloading modules
- Not using lazy-loading (actually this ruins performance and still shows other wicked errors on iOS)

### Working environments

- Chrome (Windows - Linux - macOS - Android)
- Firefox (Windows - Linux - Android)
- Edge
- IE11
- Safari on macOS

### Failing environments

- Safari on iOS (tried on a device and using Lambdatest Realtime browser testing)
- Chrome on iOS (tried using Lambdatest Realtime browser testing)
- FF on iOS (tried using Lambdatest Realtime browser testing)

### Some files/logs that may help

- Angular tools version : https://pastebin.com/Q5MpRvxV
- Broswerslist : https://pastebin.com/Uasz4YXf
- `package.json` : https://pastebin.com/UQMM2jKv
- `angular.json` : https://pastebin.com/JeBQUmeQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, It was a piece of code I've written before that is not supported in macOS, which is Positive Lookahead and Lookbehind in RegExp.

Comment: How were you able to drill down the issue?